# Eclipse error: "make: *** No rule to make target `all'. Stop."

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, java-native-interface, windows-10

## Background for the question

When I studied CS in the university, we had to build a CBIR project with C (and we got C++ file that does all the "hard work" of image processing).

Now I'm trying to create this project in Java.

I didn't know how to implement in Java some of the things in that C++ file, so I decided to use JNI and call that file from my Java program.

I'm using this tutorial for JNI:
https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html#zz-2.6

### Development Environment

+Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (32 bit),  Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0).

+CDT plugin for Eclipse

+Windows 10 64 bit (I use eclipse 32-bit because at some point, the 64-bit eclipse couldn't open and the solution was to use 32-bit eclipse)

## The problem

When I do this part of the tutorial:

> Right-click on the "makefile" ⇒ Make Targets ⇒ Create ⇒ In "Target Name", >enter "all". Repeat to create a target "clean".
>
> Run the makefile for the target "all", by right-click on the makefile ⇒ Make >Targets ⇒ Build ⇒ Select the target "all" ⇒ Build

It seems like it's working well.

But when I run the program (as was advised in "Step 5: Run the Java JNI Program"), although the program prints to the console what I wanted,after it finished running, Eclipse show me:

```
Unresolved inclusion: <jni.h>
```

in both the c++ file and the header file.

And I checked and I do have jni.h file in the path that I wrote in the makefile ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\include").

Also, I would like to know how to compile after my next changes to the cpp/h files.

## Edit:

Now I noticed that before running the program, there is a Warning in the "Problems" tab:

> Invalid project path: Include path not found (Program Files >(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\include).

But I don't understand why it's written as "Program Files" instead of "C\Program Files".

## Edit2:

I created a new project in the hope that it will solve the problem.
When I did "build" to the target "all", I got the error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.
```

I saw that someone suggested to check "Generate Makefiles automatically" (In Project properties -> C/C++ Build) but when I did it, I saw on the console "nothing to build for project CBIR2"

So I did again "build" to the target "all" and in some "magical" way, that error disappeared.

Then it seemed like the run is ok (even though the running time is very long) , but when I checked the "Problems" tab, I saw again the error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.
```

So I did again "build" to the target "all" and that error disappeared .

But obviously something is wrong here if I get that error every time that I run the program, and also before the first time that I run the program.

## makefile

```
# Define a variable for classpath
CLASS_PATH = ../bin

# Define a virtual path for .class in the bin directory
vpath %.class $(CLASS_PATH)

all : SPImageProc.dll

# $@ matches the target, $< matches the first dependency
SPImageProc.dll : SPImageProc.o
    gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -shared -o $@ $<

# $@ matches the target, $< matches the first dependency
SPImageProc.o : SPImageProc.cpp SPImageProc.h
    gcc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\include\win32" -c $< -o $@

# $* matches the target filename without the extension
SPImageProc.h : SPImageProc.class
    javah -classpath $(CLASS_PATH) $*

clean :
    rm SPImageProc.h SPImageProc.o SPImageProc.dll
```

## SPImageProc.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SPImageProc.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_SPImageProc_saySPImageProc(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {
   printf("SPImageProc 333!\n");
   return;
}
```

## SPImageProc.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class SPImageProc */

#ifndef _Included_SPImageProc
#define _Included_SPImageProc
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     SPImageProc
 * Method:    saySPImageProc
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_SPImageProc_saySPImageProc
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

## CBIR.java

```
public class CBIR {




   public static void main(String[] args) {

      SPImageProc.example();
   }
}
```

## SPImageProc.java

```
public class SPImageProc {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("SPImageProc"); // SPImageProc.dll
    }


    // Declare native method
    private native void saySPImageProc();



    public static void example() {


        // Allocate an instance and invoke the native method
        new SPImageProc().saySPImageProc();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick look at the tutorial seems to indicate that it was designed for linux or cygwin running on windows. Is this what you are doing, or are you running directly on windows? Pretty sure executing a makefile on windows (without cygwin) will fail no matter how hard you try.

Comment: I'm doing only the part  "JNI in Eclipse". 
Do you think that this part was also designed for  linux or cygwin running on windows?

Comment: @Alain And do you think this tutorial is good enough for what I'm trying to do? https://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/eclipse_CDT_JNI_MinGW_64bit.php

Comment: Using JNI involves compiling C++ code and Windows doesn't come with a C++ compiler. Hard to tell about the tutorial since I don't know how much programming you have done and how much time you are willing to invest. Give it a try. Another option if you expect to do lots of programming in the future and have the time now would be to get some linux box (look at Virtualbox) and do your work on it. Longer startup time (maybe) but less trouble in the long run. With cygwin or minGW you'll constantly be tripping on issues related to paths (spaces in directory name, where is the root, etc.)

Comment: I'm trying this tutorial but I'm stuck because something there confuses me. 
The title of that tutorial and the the first and third title says "CDT".  But in the first part of the tutorial ("Install"), it seems like the first install is eclipse for java and the second install is cdt plugin for that eclipse. 

I also don't understand that part "Eclipse Setup". Because it says "Put the source code" but I don't understand which source code, and how can I do it now if the "Creating Java Project" comes after it.

Comment: These tools easily get confused when the paths have spaces (w.g. `Program Files`). The easy fix is to copy your **jdk** to say `CL\ProgramData\jdk`.

Comment: Still haven't read the tutorial, so what follows may be wrong, but still: CDT contains the C/C++ development tools. Eclipse has lots of options as far as installing is concerned. From your original post it looks like you already have CDT installed so you can skip this part of the tutorial. As for the source code/project issue, it is possible in Eclipse to create a new project and specify an existing directory for the project location, in which case all the files become part of the project. I suspect this is what the tutorial is asking you to do.

Comment: @AlexCohn and then where do I need to update the path to the new path? 

And also, where do you recommend me to put that "CL" folder?

Comment: `CL` was a typo. I wanted to say `c:\ProgramData\jdk`. And you wrote that this path you *wrote in the makefile ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\include").*

Comment: @AlexCohn I tried it and when I try to build the target "all", I get on the console : "make: *** No rule to make target `HelloJNI.c', needed by `HelloJNI.o'.  Stop."

Comment: Looks like the message `make` would give if it didn't find `HelloJNI.c`. Are you sure the file is there, with the right upper/lower cases? Also you can right click on a HelloJNI in Eclipse and select `refresh`. It shouldn't  be necessary but it won't hurt.

Comment: Update:
I realized that I was trying to do it on cpp file, when in the makefile it says C file (and also in the tutorial. So I started the tutorial that in my original post (not the one in the comments). everything went well until the point of building the "all" target- because in the tutorial, the second line that should be printed to the console is "javah -classpath ../bin HelloJNI" and it doesn't print that line to my console.

Comment: And also, the main problem is that when I run it, even though it does print "Hello World!", I see error in the "Problems" tab  "make: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop."